# Dynamically resizing a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with 2 `UILabel` and a `UIImage` with a similar layout:

```
 --------------------
 |                   |
 |    LABEL1         |
 |    IMAGE          |
 |    LABEL2         |
 |    ......         |
 |    ......         |
 --------------------
```

Label2 has a variable number of lines, different between cells, and I would like to be able to autosize the `UICollectionView height` according to `label2 height`, to let it "autofill" the cell.
Is it possible to do it in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override following method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to dynamically calculate height of UICollectionViewCell, set the constant values according to your requirements.

```
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UIFont *fontLabel1 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    UIFont *fontLabel2 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    int padding = 5;
    int maxWidthOfLabel = 300;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidthOfLabel, CGFLOAT_MAX);

    NSString *strLabel1 = @"Label one text";// Get text for label 1 at indexPath
    NSString *strLabel2 = @"Label two text";// Get text for label 2 at indexPath

    NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
    NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;

    NSDictionary *attr1 = @{NSFontAttributeName: fontLabel1};
    NSDictionary *attr2 = @{NSFontAttributeName: fontLabel2};

    // Calculate individual label heights
    CGFloat heightLabel1 = [strLabel1 boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                options:options
                                             attributes:attr1
                                                context:nil].size.height;
    CGFloat heightLabel2 = [strLabel2 boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                options:options
                                             attributes:attr2
                                                context:nil].size.height;
    CGSize sizeOfImage = CGSizeMake(50, 50);

    // Calculate height based on all Views (2 Labels + 1 ImageView)
    CGFloat height = heightLabel1+heightLabel2+sizeOfImage.height+2*padding;
    CGFloat width = collectionView.frame.size.width;// Set width
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Why was this the accepted answer when @Chris was asking about UICollectionViewCells?  Not the same thing as UITableViewCell...

Comment: Agree with Greg. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Updated the answer to calculate height of UICollectionViewCell.